# Trouble retrieving and storing pointers to OpenGL functions manually

Tags: c++, linux, windows, opengl, graphics

I have some trouble retrieving and storing manually the pointers to OpenGL functions, here is a "simplified snippet" version of my code :

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif

#include <GL/gl.h>

class CGLManager
{
public:
    // Manager functions
    bool GetAnyGLFuncAddress( const char *_cName, void *_pFunc );
    bool LoadFunctions( void );

    // OpenGL functions
    void (APIENTRY *glBegin)( GLenum mode );
    void (APIENTRY *glEnd)( void );
    void (APIENTRY *glVertex3f)( GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z );

private:
#ifdef WIN32
    HMODULE m_hLib; // opengl32.dll
#else
    void *m_hLib; // libGL.so
#endif
};
```

And here's the source :

```
extern CGLManager gGL;

// GetAnyGLFuncAddress - Attempt to retrieve the OpenGL function named "_cName" and store it in "_pFunc", returns true if success or false otherwise
bool CGLManager::GetAnyGLFuncAddress( const char *_cName, void *_pFunc )
{
#ifdef WIN32
    // Similar to https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions#Windows
    _pFunc = (void *)wglGetProcAddress( _cName );
    if ( _pFunc == 0 || (_pFunc == (void *)0x1) || (_pFunc == (void *)0x2) || (_pFunc == (void *)0x3) || (_pFunc == (void *)-1) )
        _pFunc = (void *)GetProcAddress( m_hLib, _cName );
#else
    // TODO: Test this
    // According to some websites, NVIDIA drivers prefer the ARB implementation over the core one
    _pFunc = (void *)glXGetProcAddressARB( _cName );
    if ( _pFunc == 0 || (_pFunc == (void *)0x1) || (_pFunc == (void *)0x2) || (_pFunc == (void *)0x3) || (_pFunc == (void *)-1) )
        _pFunc = (void *)glXGetProcAddress( _cName );
#endif

    return (_pFunc != NULL);
}

// LoadFunctions - Attempt to retrieve all used OpenGL functions, returns true if all of them were retrieved or false if there is a single failure
bool CGLManager::LoadFunctions( void )
{
    if ( !(GetAnyGLFuncAddress( "glBegin", &gGL.glBegin )) )
        return false;

    if ( !(GetAnyGLFuncAddress( "glEnd", &gGL.glEnd )) )
        return false;

    if ( !(GetAnyGLFuncAddress( "glVertex3f", &gGL.glVertex3f )) )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

**Here's how my manager work in general :** it first check which renderer the game's engine uses (Software, OpenGL or Direct3D), if it's not OpenGL, then we stop getting any further. Otherwise, we load the library (`opengl32.dll` or `libGL.so`) and we check if it's good or not (again, if failed, we stop), we retrieve and store the pointers to OpenGL's functions (`glBegin`, `glEnd`, `glVertex3f`) with the `LoadFunctions` method and we return if everything's fine or something wrong happened.

**Now the problem :** the `GetAnyGLFuncAddress` method retrieve successfully OpenGL functions (in other words, `glBegin` will return true, `glARandomMethodThatDontExist` will return false) but for some reason, `gGL.glBegin` (and it's "friends") in `LoadFunctions` doesn't get updated and it will be always NULL causing a crash.

I have been trying for hours to find out a solution by searching on Internet and on StackOverflow but I haven't found any answer that can give me the solution to the problem.

In many websites and answers I've found on StackOverflow, a lot of people suggested to use an OpenGL loading library like GLEW and even the OpenGL wiki recommend it. **However, due to the nature of the environment I'm working on, I can't use those kind of libraries and neither I can't use OpenGL functions directly**, I know I'm going through the painful way by doing everything manually but I have no other choice.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Forgetting about openGL etc. for a second, how is that function going to work if you update `pFunc` (which is effectively a local temporary) inside of `GetAnyGLFuncAddress`?  That value you're setting `pFunc` to isn't going to be reflected back to the caller.  I would expect `*pFunc = whatever;`, not `pFunc = whatever`, i.e. you're supposed to dereference that pointer value.

Comment: "*However, due to the nature of the environment I'm working on, I can't use those kind of libraries*" ... It's a very odd environment indeed where you can't include a .h file and a .cpp file. Some loaders are less complicated than others.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Placing the asterisk before `_pFunc` causes an C2100 error (illegal indirection)

Comment: @Shepard62700FR: This is not a forum. Answers go in the answer section. You don't edit your question to say that it's solved.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry, won't happen again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Forgetting about what your ultimate goal is, I see basic C++ mistakes.

Let's cut out all of the code that is irrelevant and focus on this:

```
bool CGLManager::GetAnyGLFuncAddress( const char *_cName, void *_pFunc )
{
    _pFunc = (void *)wglGetProcAddress( _cName ); // <-- This sets the local pointer
    //...
}
```

Then you call the above like this:

```
bool CGLManager::LoadFunctions( void )
{
    if ( !(GetAnyGLFuncAddress( "glBegin", &gGL.glBegin )) )
        return false;
}
```

You're passing the address in the second argument, but inside the function `GetAnyGLFuncAddress`, you're not updating the value so that the new value is reflected back to the caller.  You're setting the local value instead, thus `gGL.glBegin` (and all the other addresses from the other two calls), will not be set.

Inside of `GetAnyGLFuncAddress`, I would have expected this to work:

```
bool CGLManager::GetAnyGLFuncAddress( const char *_cName, void *_pFunc )
{
    *_pFunc = (void *)wglGetProcAddress( _cName ); // <-- Note the *
    //...
}
```

And any subsequent usage of `pFunc` inside of `GetAnyGLFuncAddress` also should reflect the dereferenced value.

---

Another solution (and since this *is* C++), you can forego the `void *` C-like coding and make the function a template that takes a function pointer type as the template argument:

```
template <typename FnPtr>
bool CGLManager::GetAnyGLFuncAddress( const char *_cName, FnPtr* _pFunc )
{
    *_pFunc = reinterpret_cast<FnPtr>(wglGetProcAddress( _cName )); 
    //...
}
```

Since the type is now `FnPtr*`, whatever you pass in will automatically have `FnPtr` be of that type.  No more `void *` (except for the return value of `wglGetProcAddress`, which is casted).

Comment: If I do this and I change the prototype to `const char *_cName, void **_pFunc`, I have errors related to casts (see @Nicol Bolas answer when he suggested that I should return the pointer instead of assigning and returning success/failure)

Comment: @Shepard62700FR You can probably alleviate this error if you used a template function instead of `void *`.  See my edits.

Comment: This fixed my problem and the issue seems to be solved, no more crashes and `gGL.glBegin` and the rest are no longer NULL, thank you ^^

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> bool CGLManager::GetAnyGLFuncAddress( const char *_cName, void *_pFunc )
> ```

This is just common, broken C++. `_pFunc` is a `void*`. The pointer is the value. Changing the value of `_pFunc` *will not* change the value of the variable passed in.

You should either just return the pointer (with NULL representing the failure condition), or `_pFunc` should be a `void**`. That will likely require a cast from the caller though, and `GetAnyGLFuncAddress` would need to do `*_pFunc =` to set the value.

If you're going to return the function pointer, then you need to cast the returned `void*` to the appropriate function pointer type before storing it. This is why you often see OpenGL loaders use typedefs for function pointer types.

```
typedef void (APIENTRY *(PFN_GLBEGIN))( GLenum );

...

PFN_GLBEGIN glBegin;

...

glBegin = static_cast<PFN_GLBEGIN>(GetAnyGLFuncAddress("glBegin"));
```

Something like that.

Comment: And note that you're returning the pointer to the function.  The OP seems to be setting the pointer via a parameter, and from the looks of it, doing it incorrectly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I realized that after posting the original version.

Comment: @NicolBolas : My first attempt was like you said : return the pointer instead of assigning it in the method and return true or false depending on sucess/failure, but for some reason I was never able to "assign" the result to `gGL.glBegin`.

Comment: @Shepard62700FR: Well of course not. This is *C++*, not C. In C++, `void*` pointers do not magically transform themselves into some other type. If you want to play games with types in C++, you have to be *explicit* about it and do appropriate casts.

Comment: @Shepard62700FR: Also, nothing happens in C++ "for some reason". If the compilation failed, it would have told you what that reason was.

Comment: @NicolBolas : Thanks for those explanations, your answer is another working solution for people who prefer to return the pointer directly

Answer (score -1):

`*gl*GetProcAddres` is specified only for returning entry point addresses for *extended* functionality. It is not required that it returns addresses for functions found in the operating systems OpenGL ABI requirements (OpenGL-1.1 for Windows, OpenGL-1.2 for Linux Softare Base (LSB) 4, OpenGL-2.1 for LSB-5).

In general if your program binary is *directly linked to the API library (stub)* (in contrast to using a loader that loads the API library (stub) at runtime, dynamically), it's quity silly to retrieve functions being part of the OS's OpenGL ABI contract with `*gl*GetProcAddress` as these function are available through the regular API library anyway. `wglGetProcAddress` is exported alongside OpenGL-1.1 functions as is `glXGetProcAddress` exported alongside all OpenGL-1.2 functions (at least), so if your program sees the `*GetProcAddress` functions it also sees the other OpenGL functions.

The only reason to load *all* OpenGL symbols through GetProcAddress is if you load `opengl32.dll` with LoadLibrary or `libGL.so` with dlopen.

Comment: Having written several OpenGL loaders, it makes the loading code so much simpler if it works the same on every platform. You don't have to select between function declarations and function pointer declarations based on what platform you're using; everything is *always* a function pointer. Your loader can then just loop through all of the functions and load them; it doesn't have to have `#ifdef WINDOWS` to check to see if it should load GL 1.1 pointers or not.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Nothing in my answer denies your statments. In fact the very last paragraph is to account for methods as found in gl_LoadGen

Comment: "*In general it's quity silly to retrieve functions being part of the OS's OpenGL ABI contract*" That is the problem I have with your answer. It is not "quite silly" at all; it's entirely reasonable. Indeed, if you're writing a loader, I would argue that it's quite silly *not* to load all of the function pointers. Also, the OP does load `opengl32.dll`, which is where `m_lib` comes from in his call to `GetProcAddress`. Granted, he doesn't show the loading of the module, but it must have happened for that call to work.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, it was worded a little bit biased. I edited the answer in that regard. When it comes to OpenGL loaders are IMHO a two-edged sword: Not using a loader gives direct feedback at program start if something in the system configuration is broken or lacks capabilities. Having a loader allows to give user friendly diagnostics. Also loaders are the only way to implement higher functionality libraries that depend only optionally on OpenGL or other APIs (for example my volume rasterizer library, which may use a 3D API but will not break the program if none is available)

Comment: @NicolBolas and @datenwolf : Thanks for those explanations, for the sake of clarity, I haven't posted the initialize/shutdown methods because the issue wasn't there, but there is indeed a `m_hLib = LoadLibrary( "opengl32.dll" );`/`m_hLib = dlopen( "libGL.so", RTLD_LAZY );` and a `FreeLibrary( m_hLib );`/`dlclose( m_hLib );` involved